# Displaying error messages in index.html thrown by controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling

I am trying to implement a voucher system via pushing relevant buttons and I want it to display unique error messages on the page if user is not eligible for the discount.

```
    <tr name="vouchers">
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="five-pound-voucher" ng-click="ctrl.addFiveVoucher()">£5 off voucher
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="ten-pound-voucher" ng-click="ctrl.addTenVoucher()">£10 off voucher
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="fifteen-pound-voucher" ng-click="ctrl.addFifteenVoucher()">£15 off voucher
    </button>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td>DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE HERE</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
```

My discount methods look similar to this:

```
self.addFifteenVoucher = function() {
    if(self.subTotalPrice >= 75  && self.containingShoes) {
        self.fifteenPoundVoucher = true;
        self.setTotal();
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Not Eligible for £15 discount")
    }
}
```

Is there way to display this error message with angular without using flash messages or jquery. ng-message does not seem to be the right thing to use.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/angular-flash/

Answer (score 2):

I'd push errors into an array on the controller side and display it like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="validationErrors.length">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="error in validationErrors">
    {{error}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

inside where you have

```
<td>DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE HERE</td>
```

you could set up a bootstrap styled error message and bind it to a message set from your controller as seen below.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-if="errorMessage">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only" data-ng-bind="errorMessage"></span>
</div>
```

you could set this errorMessage property you are binding to in the else block where you were previously throwing an error. would look something like below

instead of

```
else {
    throw new Error("Not Eligible for £15 discount")
}
```

do

```
else {
    //possibly $scope.errorMessage depending on how you use your controller
    self.errorMessage = "Not Eligible for £15 discount"; 
}
```

Comment: This seems an interesting way of doing it but is only displaying the error block all the time without displaying the text, i'll have a play around with it and see if I can get it to work

Comment: Ah yes, that can be easily fixed. I will adjust above. All you need is to have an ng-if on your error block on the errorMessage property. This will only have that error block in the DOM when there is something in errorMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an Error should be only used in technical use cases and not for application logic.

Use a service to post a new 'error' and a directive, which will render there 'errors' - have a look at the [Bootstrap alert module](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert). There are hundreds and thousands of implementation on the internet. Pick the one which is right for you.